# How to use struct.pack when the data and the size to pack is undefined in advance

Tags: python, struct, pack

I need to dynamically generate a binary file from CSV file.

Example:

```
CSV file:
#size, #data
1    , 0xAB
2    , 1234              (0x04D2)
5    , "ascii"           (0x6173636969)
1    , "\x23"            (0x23)

Expected binary file:
'\xAB\x04\xD2\x61\x73\x63\x69\x69\x23'
```

The data can be a string, unsignedinteger or an hexadecimal value.
In my program i process as follow:

- I read size/data data from CSV file
- I use `eval` function to get data value
- I use Struct.pack function to generate output data

The problem is how to use Struct.pack function in order to process string or value.

I tried this:

- check isinstance(value, basestring) to handle string
- but i dont know how to handle the unsigned value defined in hexadecimal (but i dont know how to specify the format type for special size eg: 5 Byte)

I am thinking about putting any value into a hexadecimal string ...

What is the simplest way to handle (string/unsigned value to defined sized binary output)

Comment: You can split the unsigned number to normal size, ex: 5 byte = 1 + 4 byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter a string, you just need to use `encode` to get a byte string from it. If you encounter a value, just try to convert it to an int in base 10 or 16 and then use `struct.pack`:

```
formats = {
    1: "B",
    2: "H",
    4: "I",
    8: "Q"
}

def handle_value (size, value):
    try:
        value = int(value)
    except:
        try:
            value = int(value, 16)
        except:
            pass
    if type(value) == str:
        value = value[value.find('"') + 1, value.find('"') + 1 + size]
        value = value.encode("ascii") # or whatever encoding you want
    else:
        value = struct.pack(">" + formats[size], value)
    return value
```

Then to read the whole file:

```
output = bytes()
for line in files:
    size, value = line.split(",")
    size = int(size.strip())
    value = value.strip()
    output += handle_value(size, value)
```

**Edit:** I didn't notice you get the size from the CSV file, so you can infer the format you want from this size if the value is a int.

Comment: Thx for the answer, this look a lot like what i am doing right now. But i find it quite ... "dirty". Maybe converting a unsigned value to hexadecimal string is the way to go.